# how to force view controller to stay in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I have an iOS application with storyboard. I want my last viewcontroller to stay always in portrait mode. I've been reading and I found that since

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

is deprecated I should use other methods like

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate  
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

but i have tried so many combinations of this methods and I have not been able to do it. So please can someone tell me the correct way?

Comment: what iOS version are you having problems with? what is the hierarchy for the view in question? is it inside a UINavigationController, UITabBarController?

Comment: iOS 6, it's inside a UINavigationController

Comment: One way I've solved this in the past is to use a subclass of `UINavigationController` and add a property called `allowRotation`. Then each of the contained `UIViewControllers` within the `UINavigationController` can set this property as needed. The `UINavigationController` subclass can simply return this property in its `shouldAutorotate` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your UIViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController it'll never get called unless you forward on the calls yourself. (A bit of a flaw in UINavigationController in my opinion)

Subclass UINavigationController like this:

```
@interface RotationAwareNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

@implementation RotationAwareNavigationController

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIViewController *top = self.topViewController;
    return top.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIViewController *top = self.topViewController;
    return [top shouldAutorotate];
}

@end
```

Comment: You are a rock star! This has been plaguing me for years. Your solution is so nice!  Would up-vote you more than once if I could :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have UIViewControllers within other UIViewControllers (ie a UINavigationController or a UITabBarController), you will need to proxy those messages to the child object you're implementing this behavior for.

Have you set a breakpoint in your implementations to be sure your view controller is being queried?

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    if(self.window.rootViewController) {
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return orientations;
}
```

In Your ViewController:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```